# How to dispatch a call from a mediator using Simple Injector

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I have the following situation:

```
public interface ICommand { }

public interface ICommandHandler<TCommand> where TCommand : ICommand
{
    void Handle(TCommand command);
}

public interface ISepsCommandHandler<TCommand> : ICommandHandler<TCommand>
    where TCommand : ICommand
{
    event EventHandler<EntityExecutionLoggingEventArgs> UseCaseExecutionProcessing;
}

public sealed class CalculateNewAverageElectricEnergyProductionPriceCommandHandler
    : BaseCommandHandler,
    ISepsCommandHandler<CalculateNewAverageElectricEnergyProductionPriceCommand>
{ ... }

public sealed class CalculateCpiCommandHandler
    : BaseCommandHandler, ISepsCommandHandler<CalculateNewConsumerPriceIndexCommand>
{ ... }
```

In controllers I have multiple `CommandHandler`s and `QueryHandler`s in constructor and I would like to shorten it to a mediator pattern like with MediatR.

```
public interface ICqrsMediator // <TCommand, TQuery, TQueryResult>
                               // where TCommand : ICommand
{
    void Send(ICommand command);
}

public class CqrsMediator : ICqrsMediator // <ICommand
                                          // where TCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly IDictionary<Type, ICommandHandler<ICommand>> _commands;

    public CqrsMediator(
        IEnumerable<ICommandHandler<ICommand>> commands) { ... }
    ...    
}
```

Problem:

I would like to resolve a collection of `ICommandHandler` into `CqrsMediator`'s constructor. I have tried a variety of ways.

Question(s):
Why doesn't this work in SI?

```
var bla = GetAllInstances(typeof(ICommandHandler<ICommand>));
```

I get a message that it cannot find `ICommandHandler<ICommand>` but that `ICommandHandler<TCommand>` is registered, although I have given a constraint in generics that TCommand can only be of type ICommand.

Can anybody help with the construction of the mediator pattern for [CommandHandlers](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2011/meanwhile-on-the-command-side-of-my-architecture/) and [QueryHandlers](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2011/meanwhile-on-the-query-side-of-my-architecture/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why doesn't this work in SI?

This doesn't work for the same reason as this doesn't work in .NET. This would only work when your `ICommandHandler<T>` interface would be defined as *covariant*, but that is impossible because the `TCommand` is an *input* argument.

Let's remove the DI Container from the picture for a moment. Using plain-old C# code, the following is what you would like to accomplish:

```cs
ICommandHandler<ICommand> handler1 = new Command1Handler();
ICommandHandler<ICommand> handler2 = new Command2Handler();
ICommandHandler<ICommand> handler3 = new Command3Handler();

IEnumerable<ICommandHandler<ICommand>> handlers = new[] { handler1, handler2, handler3 };

new CqrsMediator(handlers);
```

The previous snippet creates three new command handlers:

- `Command1Handler` implements `ICommandHandler<Command1>`
- `Command2Handler` implements `ICommandHandler<Command2>`
- `Command3Handler` implements `ICommandHandler<Command3>`

Because you want to inject them into the `CqrsMediator`, you place them in variables of type `ICommandHandler<ICommand>`. This way you can easily construct an array (`ICommandHandler<ICommand>[]`), which can be injected into the `CqrsMediator`.

**This code, however, does not compile.** The C# compiler will state the following:

> Error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Command1Handler' to 'ICommandHandler<ICommand>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

This is the source of your problem. Your command handlers can't be cast from, for instance, `ICommandHandler<Command1>` to `ICommandHandler<ICommand>`. To understand this, you need to learn about covariance and contravariance. You might want to start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/).

To allow `ICommandHandler<Command1>` to be assignable to an `ICommandHandler<ICommand>` it requires the `ICommandHandler<TCommand>` abstraction to be *covariant*:

```
public interface ICommandHandler<out TCommand> where TCommand : ICommand { ... }
```

In other words, you need to make `TCommand` an `out` argument.

But this can't be done, because `TCommand` is actually an `in` argument (thus contravariant).

Long story short, due to the way variance and generics works in .NET (and I would actually say: in math) this is impossible.

There are two simple solutions for your problem, however.

1. Make the `CqrsMediator.Send` method generic:

```cs
public class CqrsMediator : ICqrsMediator
{
    private readonly Container container;

    public CqrsMediator(Container container) => this.container = container;

    public void Send<TCommand>(TCommand command)
    {
        var handler = this.container.GetInstance<ICommandHandler<TCommand>>();
        handler.Handle(command);
    }
}
```

2. Alternatively, if making the `Send` method generic is not an option, you can also use reflection inside the `Send` method to find the command's correct type:

```cs
public class CqrsMediator : ICqrsMediator
{
    private readonly Container container;

    public CqrsMediator(Container container) => this.container = container;

    public void Send<TCommand>(TCommand command)
    {
        var handlerType = typeof(ICommandHandler<>).MakeGenericType(command.GetType());
        dynamic handler = container.GetInstance(handlerType);
        return handler.Handle((dynamic)command);
    }
}
```

In both cases you let the `CqrsMediator` implementation depend on the `Container`. This means the implementation becomes an infrastructural component; it becomes part of your [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/).

Comment: Thank you, @Steven! But, would it be possible to inject a collection of ICommandHandler<TCommand> to CqrsMediator's constructor instead of the container or any other form that's not a container?

Comment: How would you inject a `TCommand` when your `CqrsMediator` isn't generic? You can't. You need the container (or a factory of some sort that can create any random handler) to get this done.